# Ajax not receiving complete JsonResult

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

**Background:**

In the view, we ask (via jquery and ajax) the controller for data from the database. The data is returned as Json, but for reasons unknown one part of the Json object is returned as null, even though it is properly set in the controller's JsonResult.

**The Code:**

The class to be returned as JsonResult

```
public class InData
    {
        public InData() { }
        public AppsWithActions[] apps { get; set; }
        public User[] users { get; set; }
        public string timePeriod { get; set; }
        public string startDate { get; set; }
        public string endDate { get; set; }
        public string dataType { get; set; }
    }
```

The Problem is the string arrays actionIds and actionNames in the following class are null in the javascript, even though they have the correct values in the JsonResult:

```
public class AppsWithActions
    {
        public AppsWithActions() { }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string[] actionIds { get; set; }
        public string[] actionNames { get; set; }
    }
```

The controller function that sets the InData and returns it to the javascript:

```
//Takes a goal setting, turns it to indata and returns a JsonResult
    public JsonResult GetIndataFromGoalSettingId(SettingId settingId)
    {
        var id = ToGuid(settingId.idString);
        GoalSetting setting = Session.Query<GoalSetting>()
            .Where(x => x.Id == id)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        var indata = TransformGoalSettingToInData(setting);
        return Json(new { returnvalue = indata }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The ajax call that returns everything correct, except the apps.actionIds and apps.actionNames

```
function getIndataFromGoalSettingId(settingId) {   
if (settingId != null) {
    settingIdIn = { "idString": settingId};

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        traditional: true,
        url: 'GetIndataFromGoalSettingId',
        data: JSON.stringify(settingIdIn),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            //...
        }
    });
}
```

}

It should be said that we have successfully used the same kind of infrastructure for getting data and returning it as Json to the javascript before, but if anyone has a better suggestion feel free to spell it out!

Comment: Any particular reason you are setting `async` to `false`?  Not sure this is an issue but curious.  Also a GET seems more appropriate than a POST here.

Comment: Async: false is set because we are drawing the data we receive with d3.js, and with async: true it starts drawing before the data is received and we end up with an empty graph. We need POST because we are also sending data to the controller to know which setting to return.

Comment: I see.  If you use the `success` callback to initiate your drawing then it won't start until the data is received and you can set `async` back to `true`.  You can still use GET to send the setting, just place it in the URL to be extracted as a route segment or use the querystring.  Anyway, this is all beside the point I suppose since I don't believe it addresses the issue you are having.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, but yeah, it doesn't address the actual issue.

Comment: What is the Type that `TransformGoalSettingToInData` returns?